# next-themes Error: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm receiving this error after installing next-themes and I'm unable to locate the exact issue.

[Error-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsIUU.png)
[Error-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtSBu.png)

I've tried deleting the node_modules folder and package-lock.json, then running `npm install`. This did not work.

I've tried clearing my next cache by deleting the .next folder and running `npm run dev` again. This also did not work.

I've seen online that I should insert `"use client"` at the top of my file, which I have done. But that also has not solved this issue.

I'm not sure what else to check at this point, but any help is GREATLY appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered same error, here is how I solved it.
add 'use client'; on top of your next-theme file it will solve it. You have to if you are using next themes you encounter this error.